# Textual vs material representation in Blade Runner cinematography

Tags: film-techniques, cinematography, blade-runner

Do the cinematography techniques in *Blade Runner* use textual representation (image as text) or material representation (image as presence) in order to convey the themes or motifs of the film? I thought it conveyed it as textual representation but when I look at it from a different point of view I can see material representation as well especially how closely we follow Deckard's character throughout the film.

The image as presence is grounded in the belief that the film image can show us the world as it really is. The image as presence may assume a subjective perspective, usually of one of the characters in the film. This subjective perspective may shift from one character to another either within a scene or from scene to scene, or it may remain constant throughout the film. This is the case, for example, when the central character serves as a narrator through whose eyes (and voice) we see (and hear) the events of the narrative. The image as presence may be presented from an objective perspective as the point of view of an omniscient narrator of a story or novel.

In the case of the image as text (or representation), the viewer is presented not only a visual perspective of what is in the frame but also an interpretative point of view. We are asked to look at the image and inquire about its meaning or how it is related to other film images with which we may be familiar. We may be simply asked to look at the image as an aesthetic, created image (much like a conceptual painting).